# Why is std::filesystem::u8path deprecated in c++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

Introduced in c++17, `std::filesystem::u8path` seems to be deprecated in c++20.

What is the reason for this choice? What should I use in c++17? What should I use in c++20?

Comment: Not sure why it was ever there, it seems like `std::filesystem::path` has a constructor that performs the same as that function.

Comment: From path page on cppreference : “For portable pathname generation from Unicode strings, see u8path”

Comment: Hmmm, true. But it also says: *If the source character type is char, the encoding of the source is assumed to be the native narrow encoding* (for constructor 6). I am pretty sure this covers unicode where unicode is the native format. It says the same in u8path: *If path::value_type is char and native encoding is UTF-8, constructs a path directly*. Maybe the note is unnecessary and the path constructor does the right thing?

Comment: Native narrow encoding is UTF-8 on Unix systems, on Windows, it's more complicated according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649388/what-is-the-native-narrow-string-encoding-on-windows

Comment: Because in C++20 path constructor supports construction from `char8_t` (a new fundamental type for representing UTF-8 encoded values). I've updated https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path to reflect this.

Comment: @cpplearner that should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: Because the C++ standards commitee has no vision for the future, nor clear design goals in their gigantic mess of a language.

Comment: @Guillaume, Unix systems (by which I assume you mean those close to POSIX) don't specify a character coding for filesystems, and in many cases you'll find a mixture of encodings due to different users' locales (e.g. I once shared a HP-UX system with names in both ISO 8859.1 and HP-Roman8).  As far as the kernel is concerned, filenames are raw byte sequences apart from ASCII `/` and \000.  Many newer environments (notably GNU) default to UTF-8, but claiming that all Unix systems use UTF-8 is a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because, thanks to the existence of the C++20 feature `char8_t`, this will work:

```
path p(u8"A/utf8/path");
```

`u8path` existed to allow the detection of the difference between a UTF-8 string and a narrow character string. But since C++20 will give us an actual *type* for that, it is no longer necessary.

---

> What should I use in c++17?

Use `u8path`. Deprecation does not mean *removed* or *inaccessible*. It merely means subject to *eventual* removal.

Comment: What should I do if I have a UTF-8 encoded `std::string`?

Comment: @jhasse: As stated in the post, "Deprecation does not mean removed or inaccessible." Use `u8path` for now, with the intent that you're eventually going to transition to having a proper UTF-8 encoded `u8string`.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks for the answer. But if i already have a 'std::string' encoded UTF8, how should i construct a 'path' from it?

Comment: @Taw: My answer has not changed: use `u8path` for now.

Comment: In the past three years, I’ve been using a `u8path` wrapper in my filesystem utilities which just calls `std::filesystem::u8path` with the warning suppressed

Comment: > Deprecation does not mean _removed_ or _inaccessible_. It merely means subject to _eventual_ removal.

Which means your code will _eventually_ break.

Comment: @Martin: Sure... eventually. What's your point? Eventually, you ought to be using `char8_t` to mean "string encoded in UTF-8".

Comment: @NicolBolas if you don't see anything wrong with a 40-year-old language still being at the stage where they introduce features in a version only to deprecate them in the next, then there's no point on having this discussion.

Comment: @Martin: I don't see what the age of C++ has to do with anything here. `u8path` was added in C++17 and deprecated in C++20. Also, would you prefer that we just not have a way to make filesystem paths from UTF-8-encoded strings at all? Because that was the choice. Sure, it would have been nice if the committee recognized in C++11 the importance of having `char8_t`. But that mistake was made 6 years before C++17.

Comment: @NicolBolas because adding a feature in a revision and deprecating it in the next is understandable in toy languages made by hobbyists, not by decades-old ISO standards defined by a committee of experts. Again, I see no point on continuing this discussion if you don't understand this very basic fact.

Comment: @Martin: But that's exactly what a "committee of experts" is likely to produce. They solve whatever problem is presented at the time, without looking at what features might be available in the future, because they're focused on the problem at hand. Each proposal is its own locked-off entity and needs to do what it needs to do. Filesystem was proposed at a time when there was no type-based way to distinguish UTF-8 strings. So it was either add a function or don't allow UTF-8 strings. The option to add a UTF-8 string was out of scope for the filesystem proposal.

Comment: @NicolBolas a commitee of experts should have at least some degree of vision for the future, and design new features in a way that they can interact nicely with the rest of the language. This is such a fundamentally basic concept that I hardly know how to make it clearer.

Funnily enough, I just found your name in an old isocpp mailing list thread regarding this exact same issue, where you very arrogantly dismissed a tentative char8_t proposal. I wonder what made you change your mind?

Comment: @Martin: "*a commitee of experts should have at least some degree of vision for the future, and design new features in a way that they can interact nicely with the rest of the language.*" That's not how the C++ committee has ever worked. "New features" are brought to the committee and discussed. And those features are considered based on what is brought to them. So when presented with `filesystem`, the committee has three options: tell them to return with a language change incorporating a UTF-8 character string, adopt the proposal as-is, or throw it out. They chose the useful option.

Comment: @Martin: "*you very arrogantly dismissed a tentative char8_t proposal*" I have no particular recollection of that. Maybe there was something wrong with the proposal as written (for example, if `char8_t` implicitly converted to `char` or something). Maybe I thought it would be better to have `char` always be assumed to be UTF-8. Maybe something else.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, in C++20 upatn - stopped working. At least in Visual Studio. Your answer is not correct.

Comment: @Optimus1: What do you mean by "stopped working"? If it doesn't compile or execute, that's a [violation of the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/depr.fs.path.factory).

Comment: "But since C++20 will give us an actual type for that, it is no longer necessary." what if we have 500K LOC with std::string as UTF8, cannot use the new types due to breaking API changes, and tthe committee decides to drop "u8path" in the future, so what can we do? Some audits do not allow using deprecated features.

Comment: @Taw: Then you have to update some of those 500K LOC. A simple cast from `char const*` to `char8_t const*` is sufficient. That is, turn `fs::u8path(str)` to `fs::path((char8_t const*)str)`. You may even be able to automate that.

Comment: @NicolBolas, thank you for the answer, probably I will do a helper func like `stringToPath(std::string_view)` and do the cast inside this function. Is there a similar solution also to replace constructs like `std::string str = fs::path::u8string` (deprecated also in C++20) that I use a lot? I hope the committee did not think that we can just replace all our strings with u8strings...

Comment: @NicolBolas your last comment is actually pretty useful, maybe consider editing your answer to include this workaround