# Does a `std::u8string` have to be UTF-8?

Tags: c++, utf-8

C++20 added `char8_t`, which is (I believe) designed to help support UTF-8 better.

String constants of the form `u8"abc"` are required by the standard to be valid UTF-8 in a `char8_t[]` array. These constants can also be turned into `std::u8string`s.

However, I can find nothing in the C++ standard which suggests that a `std::u8string` either must, or even should, contain a UTF-8 string. Is there in practice any difference between a `std::string` and `std::u8string` in terms of UTF-8 support?

Comment: [`char8_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types) - type for UTF-8 character representation, required to be large enough to represent any UTF-8 code unit (8 bits). It has the same size, signedness, and alignment as `unsigned char` (and therefore, the same size and alignment as `char` and `signed char`), but is a distinct type.

Comment: `std::u8string` is `std::basic_string<char8_t>`.

Comment: The difference is `std::string` being `std::basic_string<char>`, `char` can be signed or unsigned type whereas `char8_t` is only unsigned type.

Comment: "_String constants of the form u8"abc" are required by the standard to be valid UTF-8_": I don't see why this should be true. Malformed UTF-8 sequences are allowed as far as I can tell, e.g. `u8"\xff"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how std::u8string will be different from std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420790/how-stdu8string-will-be-different-from-stdstring)

Comment: On some systems a std::string might be encoded in EBCDIC, which makes quite a difference.

Comment: @RichardCritten, that question seems to cover a much broader area, and fails to give a specific factual answer to the question I ask, but maybe it should answer this question clearly as part of its answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, c++ does not require you to store valid utf8 in u8strings. From the compiler's perspective, `std::u8string` has exactly the same semantics as `std::string`.

But "in practice" you can expect functions taking a `u8string` argument to expect that string to be valid utf8. Even if they accept invalid utf8, they will definitely never expect your string to be latin1 encoded. The same definitely can't be said for `std::string`.

Comment: That is what I thought (I will just give people a brief while to pop up with new information before accepting your answer as valid in case we both missed something).